# Сравнение двух строк через перебор символов

Tags: java

Необходимо сравнить 2 строки, возможно ли как-то упростить код ниже, используя перебор символов?

```
import java.util.*;

class Meth{
    
   public static void abc(StringBuilder sb1, StringBuilder sb2){
       
       String s1 = sb1.toString();
       String s2 = sb2.toString();
       
       if(s1.length()==s2.length()){ 
       
       for(int i = 0;i<s1.length();i++){
           
           char c1 = s1.charAt(i);
           char c2 = s2.charAt(i);
           
           if(c1!=c2){
               System.out.print("words aren't equals");
               return;
            }
       }
       
       System.out.print("words are equals");
       return;
       
       }
        System.out.print("words aren't equals");
   }
  
}



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       
     Meth m = new Meth();
    StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("Hellosgs");
    StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("Hello");
    Meth.abc(sb1,sb2);
    
    
}
   
}
```

Comment: `s1.equals(s2)` ?

Comment: Понимаю что через equals было бы все в разы проще, но хотелось бы именно через перебор символов. Менее эффективно, но полезно для понимания работы loops

Comment: По-моему и так всё довольно просто.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во первых, если вы хотите проверить 2 строки на равенство, вам нужна функция, которая принимает 2 строки и возвращает true/false. У вас вместо этого какая ту функция, которая принимает StringBuilder (не строку) и не возвращает ничего.

Далее, вас есть такая конструкция

```
if(s1.length()==s2.length()){        
   for(int i = 0;i<s1.length();i++){...}
}
```

Она увеличивает уровень вложенности вашего кода, что увеличивает его сложность. Чтобы уменьшить сложность, надо инвертировать условие

```
if(s1.length()!=s2.length()){ строки не равны, возврат из функции}        
for(int i = 0;i<s1.length();i++){...}
```

Вы также не проверяете ваши данные на null.

Собирая все вместе получим что то типа

```
public static boolean Compare(String s1, String s2){
    if (s1 == null && s2 == null) return true;
    if (s1 == null || s2 == null) return false;

    if (s1.length()!=s2.length()) return false;

    for(int i=0; i<s1.length(); i++)
        if (s1.charAt(i)!=s2.charAt(i)) return false;

    return true;
}
```

Проверка может быть вот такой

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean match = Compare("string 1", "string 2");
    if (match)
        System.out.println("equals");
    else
        System.out.println("not equals");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, так гораздо проще и понятнее)

Comment: @daim если ответ вам помог, то галочка слева от ответа